# how to generating a matrix, display and finding elements in the matrix

Tags: java, arrays, matrix

this is the instructions.

Generate a 2D matrix (`array`) with the number of rows and columns as specified in input parameter

```java
public static int[][] generateMatrix(int row, int col)
```

The `generateMatrix` method should add random numbers between 0 and 10 to the array.

Print a 2D matrix (array)

```java
public static void displayMatrix(int[][] matrix)
```

Find the position(s) of an element in the Matrix

```java
public static void findElement(int[][] matrix, int key)
```

This method should display all the locations (row, column) where the key is found.

If the key is not found, then it should display a message such as `"___ not found"`.

For example, if the key was 5, the result of the method above is:

5 found at location (1, 0)
5 found at location (1, 1)

Add two Matrices and return the sum as a new matrix (2D Array)

```java
public static int[][] addTwoMatrix(int[][] m1, int[][] m2)
```

STEP 5: Add a main method to do the following: [10 Points]

1. Create a 2D Array (matrix) called m1 by calling the generateMatrix Method. Choose the numbers of rows and columns.
2. Create another 2D Array (matrix) called m2 by calling the generateMatrix Method. The number of rows and columns should be the same as for m1.
3. Create matrix m3 which should be the result of the addTwoMatrix method and store the sum of m1 and m2.
4. Display the three matrices created above - m1, m2 and m3.
5. Call the findElement method on any one array and look for a number between 1 and 10

Comment: What have you come up with so far?  This looks uncomfortably like you are asking us to do your homework for you.  Please show us how far you got so we can give meaningful assistance.  If you're really struggling, just focus on one part at a time.  Figure out how to get the program to receive the input parameter.  Then, figure out how to create a matrix based on that parameter and populated with random numbers.  Etc.

Comment: Please, remember to use appropriate styling when asking questions, as it improves readability. Also, please share what you have so far so we can help!